# Dockerized FastAPI autoreload faulty

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I put together a FastAPI using `docker-compose`.
So far it has been working nicely, but at some point the autoreload feature just stopped working, which slows down development - now it only detects changes after one minute or longer.

I have no clue what might have caused this behavior, I have not edited any of the docker settings, I have even gone back to previously working git-branches and rebuilt the images from scratch. I think it might be related to a recent Docker Desktop update - in that case, is there a way to revert to the previous working state?

This is my dc

```
version: "3"

services:

  api:
    build: 
      context: ./app
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    command: bash -c "uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

...and my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV CODE_SRC=app

WORKDIR /code/

ENV PATH=$PATH:/code/
ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/code/
ENV REQUIRED_PACKAGES git pkg-config

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update ; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $REQUIRED_PACKAGES ; \
    pip install poetry ; \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false ; \
    poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi ; \
    apt-get autoremove -y ; \
    apt-get clean -y ; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
```

Docker desktop for windows version.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This had me stuck for hours and I read maybe 10 questions and ALL the answers I could find on Stackoverflow.

This is my docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: nebula-api-image
    container_name: nebula-api-container
    restart: always
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

For me the key was ensuring that volumes and working_dir were both set to /app, which is where my Dockerfile copies my source code to. Here is that Dockerfile, where you can see the WORKDIR is set to /app

```yaml
ARG WORKDIR="/app"
ARG APPNAME="nebula-api"

FROM python:3.11.6-slim

# Refetch the variable names (optional but necessary for multi-stage builds)
ARG WORKDIR
ARG APPNAME

# Configure Python to not buffer "stdout" or create .pyc files
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Update the system and ensure its ready for usage
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
    gcc-11=11.3.0-12 build-essential=12.9

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
# Copy app files into container
COPY . ${WORKDIR}

# Install dependencies
# install poetry
RUN pip install poetry
# disable virtualenv for peotry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
# install dependencies
RUN poetry install

EXPOSE 8000
```

So I think you have a miss-match between the build and volume setting, and also your startup command. Try this:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  api:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    command: bash -c "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```